# why do we need ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, buffer

I am trying to understand `ArrayBuffer`.

It seems like that if we use `uint8Array` directly, we get everything we need(typed array with fixed type).

We can do something like this:

```
var a = new Uint8Array(2)
a[0] = 10
a[1] = 20;
```

we can even do this = console.log(a.buffer) which means we still have a buffer meaning that Uint8Array itself is a buffer.

So why do we need `ArrayBuffer` class then ? What's the actual use case ?

Comment: `ArrayBuffer` is the underlying class, it is what `a.buffer` is an instance of, the TypedArrays are views into that buffer

Comment: Yes, but I've seen people creating `Arraybuffer` class first and then creating `Uint8Array` and pass ArrayBuffer to `Uint8Array` which doesn't make sense as creating `Uint8Array` is enough already

Comment: @NikaKurashvili: how about you've got a file with 64 bit floats stored in the binary format and you want to read that file into an actual array of floats in your program?

Comment: @georg can you answer with an example ? what would `ArrayBuffer` class help you with ?

Comment: basically, `new Float64Array(await someFile.arrayBuffer())`

Comment: I don't see where you used `ArrayBuffer` class. Seems like we don't directly use it, and it happens behind the hood

Comment: Yes, this is correct. There are plenty of classes that rarely if ever need to be instantiated directly (e.g. `Promise`, `HTMLElement`). That doesn't mean we don't "need" them.